# Magento 2 Stock Alert not working for every store

Tags: magento2.3, email

Hope you can help me. I could not find a specific thread regarding this issue.

I have a question regarding stock alerts in Magento 2.3.2. I have a multistore (with shop 1 through 5). They are basically translations.

**The problem: When a product is in stock again Magento should send out stock alerts. It does so, but only for store 1, but not store 2/5**.

I have checked the settings in Configuration > Catalog > Catalog. For every scope of the multistore Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock is enabled.

I am kinda at a loss on how to proceed next. Is it a know Magento 2.3.2. bug or are there areas I haven't looked yet?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this same issue, I have fixed this with following Code. By creating new module.

**Step1:** Please Create new Module then enable it.

**Step2:** Now add 2 files **1st is di.xml** and **2nd is AddinventoryDataObserverOSC.php**

**Put the code in di.xml**

> Path: app\code\Oscprofessionals\OrderOos\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserver" type="Oscprofessionals\OrderOos\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserverOsc" />
</config>
```

**Put the code in AddinventoryDataObserverOSC.php**

> Path: app\code\Oscprofessionals\OrderOos\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserverOsc.php

```
<?php
/*
* @author      Oscprofessionals Team (support@oscprofessionals.com)
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2019 Oscprofessionals (http://www.oscprofessionals.com)
* @category    Oscprofessionals
* @package     Oscprofessionals_OrderOos
*/
namespace Oscprofessionals\OrderOos\Observer;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserver as AddInventoryDataObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class AddInventoryDataObserverOSC extends AddInventoryDataObserver
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            //$this->stockHelper->assignStatusToProduct($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!!